# How to retrieve all the values of RHS and putting it into an array using jolt transform

Tags: json, jolt

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "vedhh"
  },
  {
    "name": "guru"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "Registered_Names" : [ "vedhh", "guru" ]
}
```

The spec I'm currently using now is mentioned below. It takes both keys and values and I want to only take a list of values and make it an array of strings.
Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Registered_Names[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dive one level deeper in order only to extract the ***values***, but not the ***key names*** so as to form the desired *array* such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "Registered_Names[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```